# Install compass 1 pre fails

Tags: ruby

I can not install compass version 1.

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p0 (2011-10-30 revision 33570) [x86_64-linux]
```

And when I do:

```
$ sudo gem install compass --pre
```

I get following error:

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing compass:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 extconf.rb
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- mkmf (LoadError)
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from extconf.rb:4:in `<main>'
Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/ffi-1.9.3 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/ffi-1.9.3/ext/ffi_c/gem_make.out
```

Any idea how to fix this? I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

Comment: if anyone encounters the same proble, then isntalling ruby-dev will fix this issue

Comment: thanks @Tanel please note that the installation of 'ruby-dev' is via APT, not a gem install.

Comment: You should put it up as an answer, not a comment (it is OK to answer yourself as long as you are correct:)